# How to change repository to push to in visual studio code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have a file, that previously I pushed to a repository, however, I do not want to push to this repository anymore, and I want to push to a newly created repository. How do I switch the repository  I push to in visual studio code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention anything about keeping history or merging changes from one repository to another, so I will assume that isn't important. Why not just clone the new repository to a new (unrelated) directory and drop your file(s) there? That is the easy-to-remember and pragmatic solution to tracking changes to a new repository locally.

Comment: How do I then get vsc to push to the repo?

Comment: If you clone a repo from a git server to a folder, it will push back to that remote by default.

Comment: Isn't cloning a repo just copying a repo in github

Comment: I'm talking about the git operation of cloning, which means something different than in other SCM systems. Git is a distributed SCM; the entire repo gets 'cloned' when you work with it locally. If you aren't familiar with Git, then I recommend you read an article or two on the git basics before you continue working with github. Git is very idiosyncratic/peculiar. It feels like it has its own language / terminology sometimes.

Comment: Why isnt' there a simpler way to just change where you want to push

Comment: SCMs are built around a workflow of taking a known starting point, applying changes locally, and then merging those changes back with the server.

SCM Features like branching and merging assume that the code you are pushing shares some known starting point with the recipient of those changes. Its not like a file share you can dump arbitrary files to, its explicitly meant to track changes over time as part of a shared development workflow.

There are features for applying disconnected changes (e.g. patches), but those uncommon and usually meant for sharing across forks (a github concept).

Comment: Is there a way for me to entirely disconnect my project in vsc from github, such that I can create a repo from vsc, and just dump all my code there again?

Comment: When a repo is cloned, it creates a ".git" hidden folder in the local directory where the repo is cloned to. If you delete that, it will just be a normal directory of files that you can do whatever you want with (such as adding them to another repository). If you are using Windows you might have to turn on showing hidden files in your folder options to see it first. Deleting the .git folder removes your local repo history, so you need to know what that means before you do it.

Comment: Thanks. However, i actually did this cause vsc just seems to be stuck at pushing the code to github, and it seems this problem has occurred with this new repo as well.